# Azure Builds - The type or namespace name 'OpenApi' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops

Given:
New to Azure Builds

I have a simple WebApi project that uses Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.  Everything works fine locally (of course) but when I try to build in Azure builds I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'OpenApi' does not exist in the namespace
> 'Microsoft'

I added the SwashBuckle and OpenApi NuGet packages to `Azure Artifacts` and referenced that in my build script.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '/12b2f6b8-fb61-4aac-a526-27a85a46a5b4'
```

/reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\WindowsBase.dll" /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\ApiApplication1.dll /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\analyzers\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\analyzers\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\analyzers\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers.dll" Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs Program.cs Startup.cs WeatherForecast.cs "C:\Users\rodneysantiago\AppData\Local\Temp.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\ApiApplication1.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn

### [error]RsWpfAndApiSolution\ApiApplication1\Startup.cs(12,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'OpenApi' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Startup.cs(12,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'OpenApi' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\agent2_work\2\s\RsWpfAndApiSolution\ApiApplication1\ApiApplication1.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\agent2_work\2\s\RsWpfAndApiSolution\ApiApplication1\ApiApplication1.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\agent2_work\2\s\RsWpfAndApiSolution\RsWpfAndApiSolution.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

[image]

Comment: is this part of different package Microsoft.OpenApi?

Comment: I added that nuget package ```nuget.exe push -Source "TeamFeed" -ApiKey AzureDevOps c:\lib\microsoft.openapi.1.1.4.nupkg``` just now to feed as well and got same message

Comment: @Rod Try to open your project locally, delete the packages, and go to `manage nuget package` to choose Package source, to see whether you'll have a successful build.

Comment: There isn't a packages folder oddly enough. I'm only using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. I updated post.

Comment: Do you mean if the package not restore locally from Azure Artifacts? Do you still get a successful build locally?

Comment: In my case, one of my NuGet sources was returning a 401 Unauthorized error. I did not see this error in the build output window. Fixing the NuGet package source caused the packages to download correctly and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and reinstall with the latest version of the same package to resolve this error. Unfortunately VS doesn't show this error but its caught in CI/CD or when you run in Command Line.